# Should I tag bad content with noindex?

Tags: noindex, user-generated-content

I have a site with a lot of use generated content. Users can down and upvote content of other users. Ratings can be negative. More or less SE style.

Should I add avoid indexing bad content? (ugc with a negative rating)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what type of pages I will noindex.

1. Pages that have no answers.
2. Pages that have duplicate question.

I don't think, you should noindex all negative posts, may be someone don't like that question, and click on negative ranks, but it does not mean that page contain bad/low quality content.
You should read this [PDF from Google.](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/howsearchworks/assets/searchqualityevaluatorguidelines.pdf), you will get many hints, about good content.

Answer (score 0):

definitely yes. You can avoid crawling of bad content also. Google also provide crawling options based on url parameters , specific path( based on robots.txt)

Comment: blocking bad content is not the right solution, lot's of Pagerank will sculpt.